# Easy way to pretty print into view or flash?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pretty-print, developer-tools, flash-message

I love being able to easily print datastrucutres into the stdout, tools like [`pretty-print`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) are great for this:

```
[8] pry(main)> foo
=> {"utf8"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"0G0OwiWMK3CRmEdOlmxgNA5VrIIm7/iHg21AOLaSywEPnDGHTtGLcLjSATY7BN5lzucIrdCwbv9M+Nw++2tuYg==", "q"=>"foobar", "commit"=>"Some submit button", "controller"=>"statics", "action"=>"create"}
[9] pry(main)> p foo
{"utf8"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"0G0OwiWMK3CRmEdOlmxgNA5VrIIm7/iHg21AOLaSywEPnDGHTtGLcLjSATY7BN5lzucIrdCwbv9M+Nw++2tuYg==", "q"=>"foobar", "commit"=>"Some submit button", "controller"=>"statics", "action"=>"create"}
=> {"utf8"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"0G0OwiWMK3CRmEdOlmxgNA5VrIIm7/iHg21AOLaSywEPnDGHTtGLcLjSATY7BN5lzucIrdCwbv9M+Nw++2tuYg==", "q"=>"foobar", "commit"=>"Some submit button", "controller"=>"statics", "action"=>"create"}
[10] pry(main)> pp foo
{"utf8"=>"",
 "authenticity_token"=>
  "0G0OwiWMK3CRmEdOlmxgNA5VrIIm7/iHg21AOLaSywEPnDGHTtGLcLjSATY7BN5lzucIrdCwbv9M+Nw++2tuYg==",
 "q"=>"foobar",
 "commit"=>"Some submit button",
 "controller"=>"statics",
 "action"=>"create"}
=> {"utf8"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"0G0OwiWMK3CRmEdOlmxgNA5VrIIm7/iHg21AOLaSywEPnDGHTtGLcLjSATY7BN5lzucIrdCwbv9M+Nw++2tuYg==", "q"=>"foobar", "commit"=>"Some submit button", "controller"=>"statics", "action"=>"create"}
```

Is there some tool that would let me pretty-print something into a view or the flash? For example, if I'm in the `Statics#create`

```
def create
  flash[:notice] = params.inspect
  redirect_to statics_url
end
```

Then the rendered html looks like:

[image]

Is there an easy way to pretty print the params so they show up in my view or flash?

I've tried using `pretty_inspect`:

application.html.erb:

```
<body>
  <% if flash[:notice] %>
    <%= render plain: flash[:notice] %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

statics_controller.rb:

```
def create
  flash[:notice] = params.pretty_inspect 
  redirect_to statics_url
end
```

But it didn't work:

[image]

Using `debug` also renders a non-pretty hash:

```
<body>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= debug(flash[:notice]) if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%#= debug(@collection) if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%#= debug(current_user) if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

[image]

### Edit

Is there a better way than `gsub`bing?:

```
<%= debug(flash[:notice].inspect.gsub(',', ",\n").gsub('\\','')) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `JSON.pretty_generate`

```
<body>
  <pre>
    <%= preserve do %>
        <%= JSON.pretty_generate(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
        <%= JSON.pretty_generate(flash[:notice]) if Rails.env.development?%>
    <% end %>
  </pre>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

Comment: `undefined method preserve for #<#<Class:0x007fd3af29db98>:0x007fd3af29c978>`

Comment: `only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed` `#to_a` helps

Answer (score 0):

You can put something like `<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>` in your `application.html.erb` file

For example if you want to see what's in your params and specific variable from controller in your view you can define how many this kind of statements you need:

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
<%= debug(@collection) if Rails.env.development? %>
<%= debug(current_user) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

For pretty output you should involve bootstrap - check [this link](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#code-mixin_and_debug) please

Comment: please see edit, is it possible to pretty print the params or flash?

Comment: I've just edited my post, you should include bootstrap to your app and then define some CSS for debug(params) output. All this is described in the link given by me in edit.